# How should I do? ParseQueryAdapter

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk, android-parsequeryadapter

I want to make SNS android application.  Posts that users have posted and relations("Likes") are loaded from my Parse.com server. I succeeded in loading posts using `parseQueryAdapter` and `ListView` in a `Fragment`. But relation ("Likes") query loading event can not be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ParseQueryAdapter<Post> mainAdapter;
ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Post> factory;
factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Post>() {
        @Override
        public ParseQuery<Post> create() {
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Post");
            query.whereEqualTo("Post_Liked", true);
            return query;
        }
    };
mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<Post>(this, factory) {
@Override
public View getItemView(final Post object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.your_list_view, null);
    }
    return v;
}};
```

So why don't you just make it so that the user can set a post to "liked" or "not liked" with true and false respectively?

Comment: hmm... I think this way is for only one user. 
When each user is loading posts, bacause each of users have different liking posts, boolean column is different for them.. 
if I perform getRelation() and change the boolean column and 
Totally load posts with ParseQuery , I have to use many requests at Parse.com...

Answer (score 0):

By default ParseQuery will not fetch relationship objects. You need to include relationship objects in ParseQuery.

```
ParseQuery<Post> postQuery= new ParseQuery<Post>("Post");
postQuery.include("likes");
```

Comment: oh.. I don't know include method. I find ParseQuery reference . 
I don't know the way using that.
I want to show a example link using this method.

Comment: I think this way is unefficient because it may need more request per item at getItemView() method..

Comment: Nope. It won'tt require more request. Its way to fetch associated object with the object in same call.

Comment: How do I use this method include()?
"Likes" need to call getReltion("Likes) method of current user.